# Invalid arugement foreach(), NULL array

Tags: php, zend-framework

Controller code:

```
public function searchAction() //search action for items
{ 
    $form = new Application_Form_Search(); //pass through search form
    $form->submit->setLabel('Search Item!'); //set submit button as 'Search item!'


    $this->view->form = $form; //pass to search.phtml

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {    //Check if 'Submit' button is clicked
         $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); //Checking the values from the 'Submit' button
         if ($form->isValid($formData)) {    //Check if form is valid

            $item = new Application_Model_Item($form->getValues());  //Plug in values into item object  
            $db = new Application_Model_DbTable_Item(); //Create an item object for DbTable_Item              
            $db->searchItem($item->getName()); //search item in DbTable_Item via the searchItem
            $this->_helper->redirector->gotoSimple('search', 'item' );


        } else {
           //If the data is not valid, redisplay the information on the form so that 
           //the user can correct appropriately.
            $form->populate($formData);  

        }
    }


}
```

Form code:

```
<?php

    class Application_Form_Search extends Zend_Form
    {
        public function init()
        {
        $this->setName('search');

        $search = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $search->setLabel('Search');
        $search->setAttrib('itemname', 'submitbutton');

        $itemname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('itemname'); //create text box for stock
        $itemname->setLabel('Search Item Name:')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('Alpha')
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty');  

        //$list->setLabel('List');      
        //remember to add the declare form elements to form
        $this->addElements(array($itemname, $search));  
        }
    }
```

Model code:

```
    public function searchItem($itemname) //search item based on itemname
    {

        $itemname = (string)$itemname; //let itemid to be integer
       // $sql = 'SELECT * FROM item WHERE `itemname` LIKE ?';
        //$row = $this->fetchRow('itemname LIKE % . $itemname . %'); //find Row based on itemid
        //$row = $this->fetchRow($sql, '%'.$itemname.'%');

        $select = $this->select() //select from usertable and memberdetail
        ->from(array('item')) //join memberdetail and usertable through memberid = username
        ->where('itemname LIKE "%?%"', $itemname);
        $row = $this->fetchAll($select);
        if (!$row) { //if row can't be found
            throw new Exception("Could not find row $itemname"); //Catch exception where itemid is not found


        }
        return $row->toArray();
    }

foreach:

    <?php var_dump($this->item); ?>
    <?php foreach($this->item as $item) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($item['itemid']);?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($item['image']);?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($item['itemname']);?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($item['description']);?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($item['itemtype']);?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hi Im trying to do a search page but I kept getting the foreach() error. Did a var_dump and it says NULL. Wondering where I have gone wrong. Stuck at the same problem for hours before deciding to seek help from you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a case where you dont give any value to $item. You may try add

```
ing:
    } else {
               //If the data is not valid, redisplay the information on the form so that 
               //the user can correct appropriately.
                $form->populate($formData);  
                $item = array(); //add this here or before the if block    
            }
```

else add...

```
<?php if(!is_null($this->item)){ ?>
    <?php foreach($this->item as $item) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($item['itemid']);?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($item['image']);?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($item['itemname']);?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($item['description']);?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($item['itemtype']);?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesnt print out any errors now. But my array still returns NULL. Wonder if it might be due to the SQL

Comment: check if you manage to get in the if block try something like

$item = new Application_Model_Item($form->getValues());
echo "Validation passed" exit;

Comment: I did tried to echo sth in the if block but it doesnt print. But $this->_helper->redirector->gotoSimple('search', 'item' ); still redirects me although it is in the if block.

Comment: Are you sure that this line redirects you. Because if u placed echo 'st';exit; in the if it shouldn't redirect. Try comment this line to see will you get redirected again.

Comment: Yes it does redirect me. Im not redirected if I commented the line.

Comment: My bad. It does print out the "Validation passed." I forgot to add the exit;

Answer (score 0):

in foreach try:

```
$myItems = $this->item;

<?php foreach($myItems as $item) : ?>
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesnt print the items.